# Relatively free algebras in a variety generated by a single algebra

Tags: gr.group-theory, universal-algebra

Suppose $A$ is an algebra of signature $\mathcal{L}$ and $V=Var(A)$ is the variety generated by $A$. I want to know is it possible to classify relatively free elements of $V$? As a special case, for a group $G$, under what conditions $G$ is free in $Var(G)$?

Comment: In what sense do you wish to classify these?

Comment: @Benjamin Steinberg: For example I want to know is $A$ free relative to $V$? From one side it seems that the answer is YES because $A$ satisfies exactly the same identities as the defining identities of $V$. On the other side, I have a sense that says this may be not true.

Comment: A will not in general be free in V. For example, the group S_3 is not free in the variety. If it were it would be free on 2-generators. Both generators would have to have the same order and hence must be of order 2. But then the map sending these generators to a 3-cycle and a 2-cycle does not extend.

Comment: Another counterexample: The variety of Boolean algebras is generated by *any* non-trivial boolean algebra $A$ (because the 2-element Boolean algebra is a subalgebra of $A$), but many non-trivial Boolean algebras fail to be free.

Comment: You might think about nonfree algebras to understand the situation.  Take a variety V generated by A.  In imteresting cases V will have many other algebras B which generate V, such as those with a subalgebra isomorphic to A.  Many of these B will not be free in V.  There will be relations revealed by looking at proper subvarieties of V.  This may help you find those B which generate V and are not free in V

Comment: @Benjamin Steinberg: very good, my question is now well-understood: another counterexample is the quasi-cyclic group $C_{p^{\infty}}$. But why? This seems paradoxical! From one hand we have  $Var(A)=Mod(id(A))$ (the class of all algebras satisfying identities of $A$), on the other hand $A$ should satisfy exactly and only the same identities as defining identities of $V$. So $A$ must be free in $V$!!!!

Comment: To amplify the example above, the variety of groups generated by S_3 contains the cyclic groups of orders 2,3, and thus 6.  This last is definitely not a homomorphic image of S_3, which it would have to be if S_3 were free and you had to build a 1-generated algebra in the variety.

Comment: @Andreas Blass and The Masked Avenger: thank you so much for counterexamples. But what about positive examples? ( I mean algebras $A$, which are not free in  some large variety but are free in $Var(A)$). Especially for a group $G$, exactly when $G$ is free in $Var(G)$?

Comment: I give a decidable criterion in my answer for finite universal algebras.  Essentially a finite universal algebra $A$ is free iff it is free in the variety it generates, iff for any minimum size generating set $X$, one has every map from $X$ to $A$ extends to an endomorphism.  Moreover, all minimum size generating sets are free generating sets.

Comment: @Benjamin Steinberg: Do you mean: a finite algebra $A$ is free in some variety $V$ iff it is free in $Var(A)$? This is seems to be trivial even if $A$ is not finite: since if $A$ is free in some variety $V$, then clearly it will be free in the "sub-variety" $Var(A)$. The other side is trivial.

Comment: In general an algebra $A$ is relatively free in some some variety $W$ iff it is relatively free in $Var(A)$.  The point is if $B$ is the relatively free algebra in $Var(A)$ on the same generating set as $A$ is free in $W$, then $B$ belongs to $W$ because $A$ does.  Hence there is a canonical surjective homomorphism $A\to B$ preserving bases.  But by definition, there is a canonical surjective homomorphism $B\to A$ preserving bases.  So these are inverses to each other.  Thus the notion of a universal algebra being relatively free makes sense without mention of some ambient variety.

Comment: @user449949, not just finite ones.  Any universal algebra. See my last comment.

Comment: @user44949, your confusion is that you seem to think that the fact that $A$ satisfies the same identities as the free algebra in $Var(A)$ on say $|A|$-generators should make $A$ free.  There is extra symmetry in free objects.

Comment: For instance take the variety of semigroups with zero defined by $xyz=0$.  It is generated by the $S=\{a,b,ab,0\}$ where $a^2=b^2=ba=0$ but $S$ is not relatively free because of the lack of symmetry between $a,b$.

Comment: Benjamin Steinberg: I am trying to understand the point you said: Let $V$ be the variety of all groups and $\Sigma$ be a set of identities which defines $V$, i. e. $V=Mod(\Sigma)$. Let $F_2$ be the free group of rank 2. Then $id(F_2)=\Sigma$  and so $F_2$ is free in $V$. Clearly $Var(F_2)=V$. On the other hand $F_1$ is also free in $V$ but $id(F_1)$ is larger than $\Sigma$. Maybe this is the point!

Comment: By summarizing the above comments, now I can give an  example: Let $V$ be the variety of nilpotent groups of class $\leq c$. Let $G\in V$ be free, so $G$ is not a free group, however  it is free in $Var(A)$.

Comment: But the main problem is open: What is the necessary and sufficient condition for a group to be free in $Var(G)$? For example which elements of $Var(S_3)$ are free? Note that the rank 1 free element of $Var(S_3)$ is $C_6$, the cyclic group of the order 6. So what is the rank $n$ free element of this variety?

Comment: @M.Shahryari, my answer gives the necessary and sufficient conditions for a finite group to be relatively free. It is algorithmic and probably co-NP. What more do you want? For specific examples look in Hanna Neumann's book or in the literature.

Comment: @Benjamin Steinberg: thank you, now I understand your argument. Now, for example any cyclic group, and any elementary abelian group is relatively free by your argument. It will be very good if one can find a classification of finite relatively free groups.

Comment: I think trying to classify up to isomorphism relatively free finite groups is most likely hopeless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that $A$ is a finite universal algebra with minimal cardinality of a generating set $d$.  Then $A$ is relatively free in some variety iff it is relatively free on $d$ generators in the variety it generates, in which case it is free on any generating set of $d$ elements.  Moreover, this occurs iff each map from a fixed $d$-element set generating $A$ to $A$ extends to an endomorphism.

It is easy to check that if $A$ is relatively free in some variety then it is relatively free in $Var(A)$.  Next note that if $A$ is relatively free on $k$ generators, then the cardinality of $Hom(A,A)$ is $|A|^k$.  On the other hand, $|Hom(A,A)\leq |A|^d$ and so $k\leq d$.  But $d$ was minimal, so $A$ is free on $d$ generators.  Also note that if $X$ is a free set of $d$-generators, then we can map $X$ to any other set of $d$-generators and this extends to a surjective homomorphism which is injective by finiteness.  So all $d$-element generating sets are free generating sets.

Clearly if $A$ is relatively free on $d$ generators, then any map from a $d$-element generating set (necessarily a free generating set) to $A$ extends to an endomorphism.  Suppose the converse holds.  Let $B$ be the free algebra on $d$ generators in the variety generated by $A$. It is well known that $B$ embeds in a finite product $A^m$ where $m=|A|^d$.  Let $g_i\colon B\to A$ be the projection to the $i^{th}$ factor.  If $f$ is the map taking the $d$ generators of $A$
to the free generators of $B$, then we can extend $g_if$ to an endomorphism $h_i$ of $A$ by hypothesis on $A$.  The product $h$ of these $h_i$ gives a homomorphism of $A$ to $A^m$ sending the generators of $A$ to the generators of $B$.  Hence $h$ splits the canonical surjection $B\to A$.

**Added.** This last argument doesn't require finiteness. A universal algebra $A$ is relatively free if and ony if it has a generating set $X$ such that each map from $X$ to $A$ extends to an endomorphism.

Comment: Let me to summarize the result above as I understand: A finite algebra $A$ with $d$ generator ($d=\min$) is relatively free if and only if any map from the set of $d$ generators to $A$ extends to an endomorphism. Am I right?

Comment: Yes you are right.

Answer (score 1):

More general than my comment above, but still only a partial answer: Notice that $\text{Var}(A)$ is generated by any $B\in\text{Var}(A)$ that has $A$ as a subalgebra (or quotient, or subquotient).  It would seem that only in very special varieties would all such $B$'s be free.

Answer (score 0):

Free algebras of $V(\textbf{A})$ lie in $SP(\textbf{A})$ (subalgebra of product).  Unless your algebra is trivial or very special,  I do not see a better characterization of free algebras forthcoming.